# How to define quadratic weighted kappa as eval_metric in catboost classifier

Tags: python, classification, model-evaluations, metric

I am using catboost for a multiclass classification problem. I want to use ***quadratic weighted kappa*** as the evaluation metric.

Catboost already has **WKappa** as an eval_metric but it is **linearly weighted** variant, not quadratic.

```
clf = CatBoostClassifier(objective='MultiClass',
eval_metric=q_weighted_kappa(),
learning_rate=0.01,
n_estimators=750,
od_type="Iter",
depth=35,
early_stopping_rounds=500,
random_seed=42,
```

)

I need help to define the function **q_weighted_kappa()** that I can use as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn kappa has 2 variants: simple and weigthed. It seems WKappa refers to weighted (quadratic) kappa in terms of sklearn, and Kappa - to simple.